# Exclude path in EditorConfig matching

Tags: glob, editorconfig

I want an `.editorconfig` rule that includes all `*.js` files, except all `*.min.js` files.  Is this possible to achieve?

Something like this:

```
[*.js,!*.min.js]
max_line_length = 140
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to solve this:

```
[*.js]
max_line_length = 140

[*.min.js]
max_line_length = off
```